# Apache Nifi - Change Path in Attribute with UpdateAttribute Processor

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I want to change a Flowfile-Attribute with the UpdateAttribute Processor.

The Attribute "filename" is:

```
backup/int_backup/storage/teamname/toolname/path/bdsd9d83-dvvv8-41d9-a271-95b2284bd56c/20200420125822_11.zip
```

The beginning of the string shoult be cut and between `teamname` and `toolname` should be an other folder called `archive` like:

```
teamname/archive/toolname/path/bdsd9d83-dvvv8-41d9-a271-95b2284bd56c/20200420125822_11.zip
```

I created a regex that identified the teamname:

```
/[^/]*/[^/]*/([^/]*)/
```

And a Regex that marks everythings after the third "/":

```
/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/([^*]*)
```

I tried to build up the string by adding:

```
${filename:replaceAll('/[^/]*/[^/]*/([^/]*)/', '$1')}/archive/${filename:replaceAll('/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/([^*]*)', '$1')
```

However, the result is not the regex result, it is the regex itself.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
${filename:replaceAll('^(?:[^/]+/){3}([^/]+)(.*)', '$1/archive$2')}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/imbpK8/1/)

**Details**

- `^` -  start of string
- `(?:[^/]+/){3}` - three occurrences of 1+ chars other than `/` and then a `/`
- `([^/]+)` - Group 1 (`$1`): one or more chars other than `/`
- `(.*)` - Group 2 (`$2`): the rest of the string.